# Функция isdigit работает не так, как я ожидал

Tags: c

Как можно узнать, является ли введённый символ цифрой?

Функция `isdigit` не работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int score = 0;

    while (1) {
        int x = atoi(argv[1]) + rand() % atoi(argv[2]);
        int y = atoi(argv[1]) + rand() % atoi(argv[2]);

        int operationSignNumber = 1 + rand() % 2;
        int result              = 0;

        switch (operationSignNumber) {
            case 1:
                printf("+------------------+\n");
                printf("    %i + %i =  ?    \n", x, y);
                printf("+------------------+\n");

                result = x + y;
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("+------------------+\n");
                printf("     %i - %i =  ?   \n", x, y);
                printf("+------------------+\n");

                result = x - y;
                break;
        }

        int userAnswer     = 0;
        int answerWasGiven = 0;

        printf("\n> ");
        scanf("%i", &userAnswer);

        if (!isdigit(userAnswer)) break; // <<----

        system("clear");

        if (userAnswer == result) {
            printf("+------------------+\n");
            printf("|      Right!      |\n");
            printf("+------------------+\n");

            score++;

        } else {
            printf("+------------------+\n");
            printf("|      Left!       |\n");
            printf("+------------------+\n");
        }

        sleep(1);

        int timer = 3;

        while (timer) {
            system("clear");

            printf("+------------------+\n");
            printf("| Get ready! %i...  |\n", timer);
            printf("+------------------+\n");

            timer--;
            sleep(1);
        }

        system("clear");
    }

    system("clear");

    printf("+------------------+\n");
    printf(" You score: %i...  \n", score);
    printf("+------------------+\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Программу запускаю так: `./quick_math 1 3`. Выводит `1 + 1`. Я ввожу `2` и программа закрывается. Пробовал компилировать с помощью `Clang 3.6` и `GCC-4.8.4` — результат одинаковый.

Comment: Не понятно, где вы вводите 2?

Comment: `scanf("%i", &userAnswer);`. Прямо перед функцией `isdigit`.

Comment: isdigit принимает на вход строку (массив символов). Вы же передаете число. Число будет числом. Это если бы оно было вещественным, то там может быть NaN, но для целого этой проблемы нет.

Правильно проверять результат scanf - сколько байт было прочитано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `isdigit` определяет, является ли младший байт целочисленного числа с типом `int`, заданного в качестве аргумента, символьным кодом цифры. То есть она делает не то, что вы предполагаете.

Вам просто следует заменить эти два предложени

```
scanf("%i", &userAnswer);

if (!isdigit(userAnswer)) break;
```

одним предложением:

```
if ( scanf("%i", &userAnswer) != 1 ) break;
```

Comment: @Eanmos Не за что. Мы, начинающие C++ программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, не знаю откуда ты это взял, но ты не прав по поводу младшего байта.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29646/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow----isdigit).

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, если вы считаете, что Vlad from Moscow неправильно понимает контракт `isdigit(int)`, лучше дать отдельный развернутый ответ.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, и старайтесь поддерживать [дружелюбную атмосферу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) на сайте

Comment: @Nofate для того чтобы дать правильный ответ, сначала нужно задать правильный вопрос. Я лишь пытался донести до товарища ошибку, которую он совершил.